# How to find my localhost IP address when I follow Turtlebot3 instruction

Tags: ros-kinetic, turtlebot3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I try to follow Turtlebot3 instruction. I can not find my IP address which is mentioned in 6.4 Network Configuration. http://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/pc_setup/#pc-setup .
When I check my IP address, I can not find them.

```
enp0s31f6 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 50:9a:4c:31:19:40  
          inet addr:172.16.51.164  Bcast:172.16.51.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::9df1:70a0:ebd3:f7b6/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:44832 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:15524 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:20692421 (20.6 MB)  TX bytes:2117659 (2.1 MB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f7180000-f71a0000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:5715 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5715 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:707160 (707.1 KB)  TX bytes:707160 (707.1 KB)
```

Which one is my IP address? It seems that there lacks one part of Network information when compared to the introduction.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285675/how-to-find-my-localhost-ip-address-when-i-follow-turtlebot3-instruction./) by [Pujie](https://answers.ros.org/users/34177/pujie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 106 on 2018-03-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

note: the page you link uses `ROS_HOSTNAME` with IPs, which is (technically and officially) not correct. I'm using `ROS_IP` in my answer, but if you must, just use `ROS_HOSTNAME` everywhere I've used `ROS_IP`.

---

`localhost` ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost)) is a special hostname, and the `lo` entry in the output you post would be a virtual network interface. As to it's IP, that is shown on the second line:

```
inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
```

However, that is *not* the IP address you want to use for setting `ROS_IP`, as every host in your network uses it to communicate with *itself*. That won't help if you're trying to get two PCs to communicate using ROS, as they won't be able to find each other.

The text in the manual is a little confusing (and I would report that to Robotis), but the diagram shown at the top explains quite well what is needed to set this up: `ROS_IP` *must* be set to the IP address of each host respectivel, and `ROS_MASTER_URI` *must* point to the IP address of the host running the ROS master (ie: `roscore`).

If the `ifconfig` output you included in your question is from your "Remote PC", then `ROS_IP` would have to be set to `172.16.51.164`, and `ROS_MASTER_URI` would be `http://172.16.51.164:11311`.

On your turtlebot, you'd use the same `ROS_MASTER_URI`, but set `ROS_IP` to the IP address of the turtlebot.

> It seems that there lacks one part of Network information when compared to the introduction

Note: the names `enp3s0` and `wlp2s0` entries in the `ifconfig` output in the manual are just *examples*. Each network interface gets its own name, and they may be differently named on your system.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-17**:
I would also like to add that your question is technically not a ROS question, but a system configuration one. `ROS_HOSTNAME`, `ROS_IP` and `ROS_MASTER_URI` are obviously ROS environment variables, but finding their values is not.